# How to nested loop in jquery and event.push()

Tags: jquery, loops, fullcalendar, nested-loops

I am new to jQuery and hope someone can help me with this.
I have an JSON data which are as follows

```
events: function(start, end, tz, callback) {
var events      = [];
var num_events  = [ 
    {"formId": 9,
        "fornCode": "PP40",
        "Model": [
            {"taxMonth": 0,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-10-09"
            },
            {
                "taxMonth": 3,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-11-10"
            },
            {
                "taxMonth": 10,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-12-19"
            }
        ]
    },{"formId": 18,
        "fornCode": "PP30",
        "Model": [
            {"taxMonth": 0,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-01-09"
            },
            {
                "taxMonth": 3,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-04-10"
            },
            {
                "taxMonth": 10,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-11-19"
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

I try to loop all this data like this

```
$.each (num_events, function (index, object) {
    formId      =   num_events[index].formId,
    fornCode   =   num_events[index].fornCode

    $.each (object, function (key, value) {
        if(key == "Model"){
            taxMonth                =   object[key].taxMonth,
            effectiveDate           =   object[key].effectiveDate
        }
    });
});
```

After that i try to push all events like this

```
events.push({
    "id"                        : formId,
    "fornCode"                  : fornCode,

    "taxMonth"                  : taxMonth,
    "effectiveDate"             : effectiveDate
});

callback(events);
},
```

but it only show "id and fornCode " but "taxMonth effectiveDate" is undefined 
So is there any that i can loop and push it in events?
**want to change like this**

```
{formId  : '9', fornCode  : 'PP40', taxMonth  : '0', effectiveDate  : '2018-10-09'},
{formId  : '9', fornCode  : 'PP40', taxMonth  : '3', effectiveDate  : '2018-11-10'},
{formId  : '9', fornCode  : 'PP40', taxMonth  : '10', effectiveDate  : '2018-12-19'},
{formId  : '18', fornCode  : 'PP30', taxMonth  : '0', effectiveDate  : '2018-01-09'},
{formId  : '18', fornCode  : 'PP30', taxMonth  : '3', effectiveDate  : '2018-04-10'},
{formId  : '18', fornCode  : 'PP30', taxMonth  : '10', effectiveDate  : '2018-11-19'}
```

//I am working with FullCalendar so i have to push all data in events.
I am not sure that is this good way to this, If any suggestion will be thankful to me.
Many thanks in advance. ^^

Comment: Hi, my friend. Sorry, I don't see property fornShortTh. You missed it in sample data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create new arrays from the Model object. And no need to use `if(key == "Model")`. Run the snippet and see how it works.

```js
var events      = [];
var num_events  = [ 
    {"formId": 9,
        "fornCode": "PP40",
        "Model": [
            {"taxMonth": 0,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-10-09"
            },
            {
                "taxMonth": 3,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-11-10"
            },
            {
                "taxMonth": 10,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-12-19"
            }
        ]
    },{"formId": 18,
        "fornCode": "PP30",
        "Model": [
            {"taxMonth": 0,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-01-09"
            },
            {
                "taxMonth": 3,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-04-10"
            },
            {
                "taxMonth": 10,
                "effectiveDate": "2018-11-19"
            }
        ]
    }
];

$.each (num_events, function (index, object) {
    formId      =   num_events[index].formId,
    fornCode   =   num_events[index].fornCode,
    fornShortTh   =   num_events[index].fornShortTh
    taxMonth = []
    effectiveDate = [];
    $.each (object.Model, function (key, value) {
        events.push({
            "id"                        : formId,
            "fornCode"                  : fornCode,
            "taxMonth"                  : taxMonth,
            "effectiveDate"             : effectiveDate,
            "taxMonth"                  : value.taxMonth,
            "effectiveDate"             : value.effectiveDate
        });
    });
});
console.log(events);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks once again @Rüzgar its work fine but I am still facing some problem
i would like to have all events in single line suppose if model have 2 array then split it in single line just like my included (I have update it in my question) 
Do i have to loop again to get it?

Comment: Of course. It is possible. I am quite busy right now, but i will try when i have some time.

Comment: Wow it works! Thank you sir. Thanks a lot for all your help. ^^

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to really understand what do you want to do, but maybe something like that :

```
$.each (object, function (key, value) {
    if(key == "Model"){
        $.each(value, (i, e) => {
            events.push({
                "id" : formId,
                "fornCode" : fornCode,
                "taxMonth" : e.taxMonth,
                "effectiveDate" : e.effectiveDate
             });
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @vanessa for you response i have try it when i have `console.log()` there is no data